# Matrix dimension error when adding 2 binary masks

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add 2 binary masks of the same image for overlap ratio calculation
I create the binary masks as such:

```
mask1 = roipoly(image,points1(:,1),points1(:,2))
mask2 = roipoly(image,points2(:,1),points2(:,2))
imwrite(mask1,'mask1.bmp')
imwrite(mask2,'mask2.bmp')
```

points1 and points2 are 2 different matrices of segmentation coordinates of the same size

When I try to do the following, i get `Matrix dimension must agree` error using plus

```
a=('mask1.bmp')
b=('mask2.bmp')
a+b
```

When i check the sizes of a and b they give same values but somehow the matrix dimensions don't agree

Comment: Can you check the example code? As is, the `a+b` is adding the characters of two strings together, and does not error.

Comment: There is `image` build-in function in MATLAB. Don't use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

It can be written as:

```
c=mask1+mask2;
imshow(c);
```

Comment: The answer doesn't answer the question, since it assumes that mask1 and mask2 are of the same size, where there can be cases that one will have size 0 because of user error (double clicking without ROI defined). Additionally, mask1+mask2 can create values of 2, so the matrix is no longer binary.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `imread`

```
a=imread('mask1.bmp')
b=imread('mask2.bmp')
```